# Racket: local-expanding recursive definitions

Tags: racket, metaprogramming

I'm trying to write a macro behaving just like racket define, but processing fully expanded racket procedures in some way (just expanding for simplicity in the example below):

```
(define-syntax (define/expand stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_ (head args ...) body body-rest ...)
       (let* ([define/racket (syntax/loc stx (define (head args ...) body body-rest ...))]
              [fully-expanded (local-expand define/racket 'top-level (list))])
           fully-expanded)]
    [(_ id expr) (syntax/loc stx (define id expr))]))
```

Everything is fine unless recursive definition is met:

```
(define/expand (sum n)
  (if (<= n 0)
      0
      (+ n (sum (- n 1)))))
```

Running it raises an error

> sum: unbound identifier in module in: sum

pointing the *call* of the `sum` (not the definition). Obviously the definition of `sum` is not captured by local expander. I've tried a straightforward way of fixing it: creating new local definition context and binding `head` into it:

```
(define-syntax (define/expand stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_ (head args ...) body body-rest ...)
       (let* ([ctx (syntax-local-make-definition-context)]          ; <- These two lines added 
              [_ (syntax-local-bind-syntaxes (list #'head) #f ctx)] ; <--/
              [define/racket (syntax/loc stx (define (head args ...) body body-rest ...))]
              [fully-expanded (local-expand define/racket 'top-level (list) ctx)])
           fully-expanded)]
    [(_ id expr) (syntax/loc stx (define id expr))]))
```

It solves the problem (local expanded successfully expands the procedure into `define-values`), but creates the other one:

> module: out-of-context identifier for definition in: sum

pointing the *definition* of sum. The reason is probably that expander binds identifiers to one in `ctx` instead of `head` in current context.

Intuitively it does not seem to be a rare problem, but I could not find the solution over the network. I thought that I should somehow use `local-expand/capture-lifts` and `syntax-local-lift-expression`, but I don't get how to use it properly. Could someone clarify what's going on and/or give a hint how to fix it?

Comment: Another sometimes-useful trick: call `local-expand` on a lambda binding the unbound variables, then pattern-match the result to get the body out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's try your first program in a top-level (repl):

```
#lang racket
(define-syntax (define/expand stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_ (head args ...) body body-rest ...)
     (let*
         ([define/racket  (syntax/loc stx (define (head args ...) body body-rest ...))]
          [fully-expanded (local-expand define/racket 'top-level (list))])
       fully-expanded)]
    [(_ id expr)
     (syntax/loc stx (define id expr))]))
```

and then in the repl:

```
Welcome to DrRacket, version 6.6.0.3--2016-07-28(-/f) [3m].
Language: racket, with debugging [custom]; memory limit: 1024 MB.
> (define/expand (sum n)
  (if (<= n 0)
      0
      (+ n (sum (- n 1)))))
.#<syntax:3:2 (define-values (sum) (lambda ...>
> (sum 5)
15
```

This shows that your program works at the top-level.

The reason the same approach doesn't work in a module context
is that the `#%module-begin` uses partial expansion of forms
to detect definitions before expanding expressions.
In other words define/expand must tell `#%module-begin` that
it expands into a definition of `sum` but must delay the use
of `local-expand` until `#%module-begin` has detected all
bound identifiers at the module level.

This suggests a two step approach:

```
#lang racket

(define-syntax (delay-expansion stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_delay-expansion more ...)
     (let ([fully-expanded (local-expand #'(lambda () more ...) 'module (list))])
       (display fully-expanded)
       fully-expanded)]))

(define-syntax (define/expand stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_ (head args ...) body body-rest ...)
     (syntax/loc stx
       (define (head args ...)
         ((delay-expansion
           body body-rest ...))))]
    [(_ id expr)
     (syntax/loc stx
       (define id expr))]))


(define/expand (sum n)
  (if (<= n 0)
      0
      (+ n (sum (- n 1)))))

(sum 5)
```

See more here: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/racket-users/RB3inP62SVA/54r6pJL0wMYJ

Comment: Wow, nice trick, thank you so much! It answers some other questions too.